Cathay Pacific Online Booking: When to Enter Passport Details?
First of all, sorry if this question has been asked before.
This is my first time booking a flight directly from the Cathay Pacific website. I usually use a travel app, but there's a promo ticket code that can only be redeemed on their website.
When I was filling in the passenger information, I was only asked for names and not passport numbers. I could proceed to payment without providing passport details. When I asked customer service, they said passport details could only be entered during online check-in, which is available 24 hours before the flight.
Has anyone here actually booked from the Cathay Pacific website? Can you share your experience with entering passport details later on? I'm a bit worried about this and want to make sure I won't encounter any issues.
Thanks a lot!

Where are you travelling to/from? Not all destination countries require passport details.

What specifically are you worried might happen?

There is really no particular reason for the airline to collect passport info during booking and Cathay Pacific does indeed not do that. Unless specific government regulations require passport info, the only purpose at booking would be to uniquely identify you. Cathay collects your name and date of birth and that seems to be sufficient for them.
In any case: the passport info you enter at booking is never "binding", i.e. you don't need to use that passport even if entered. The passport(s) that matter for travel are the ones you present during check-in.  This does NOT need to be the passport used during booking (if collected) and in facts it occasionally isn't. For example, your passport may get renewed between booking and flight (which can be months apart).
There is also no need to use a single passport for the entire trip. When I fly from the US to Europe, I use my Schengen passport and on the return I use my US passport (at check-in).
